# signOut pop up not being displayed after specified time

Tags: javascript, typescript, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am having a problem with my typescript code.

This code just flashes the pop-up for a second then redirects back to home page. It doesnt wait for 5 seconds like the setTimeout() should. I am using signOut from next-auth/react

```
  import { signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

  const [showSignOutAlert, setShowSignOutAlert] = useState(false);

  const handleSignOut = async () => {
    await signOut();
    setShowSignOutAlert(true);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowSignOutAlert(false);
    }, 5000);
  };

  if (status === "unauthenticated") {
    router.push("/");
  }
```

This is my sign out alert:

```
      {showSignOutAlert && (
        <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center bg-black bg-opacity-70">
          <div className="bg-white p-8 rounded-md">
            <p className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Successfully Signed Out</p>
            <p>You will be redirected to the home screen shortly...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! If there is a better way to implement this, that also works for me.

Comment: Can you tell me from where this 'status' is coming?

Comment: await setTimeout( .... )  ?